# Compose kotlin: A row with a random number of cards

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Beginner here.

I am trying to build a row composable that can hold a given number of "cards" using Kotlin/ Jetpack compose.
My goal is to have something like this
[image]

The cards do not change size *but have otherwise different content* as indicated by their different colors, they are centered horizontally and vertically.
The row does not change size, it fills the whole width.

How can I fill a row with a chosen number of such "Composable" cards?

schematically, I would like to do something like

```
Row(){arr}
```

where arr is an array, a list or anything containing these cards. I think I do not want to use lazyRow because I do not want the row to overflow or be scrollable.

my best guess up to now is something like this:

```
LazyRow(){
        items(arr.length) { i ->
            cardFun(arr[i])
        }
```

where cardFun is a function describing the cards in the row

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest making a `@Composable` for your Cards, or whatever you would like to put into the row. You could use a `LazyRow()` and set the parameter `userScrollEnabled = false` to prevent scrolling. To set a number of cards you could simply use `repeat(NUMBER_OF_CARDS) { CardComposable() }` to generate.

I would be careful that your cards don't overflow the bounds or clip out and look strange though, in that case looking into a custom `subcomposeLayout` will probably be your best bet, albeit a much more challenging one.